# Can't rename in WebStorm 9

Tags: refactoring, rename, webstorm

I have a node/react/flux (javascript) app in WebStorm 9. Every time I try and rename a file I get the following popup:

> Extract Variable is not finished yet.
>
> Continue Started ( which does nothing ) Cancel Started ( which also
>   doesn't help )

Does anyone know what this is about?

Comment: Looks like a bug in refactoring. Please restart WebStorm - can you rename a file now? I can suggest creating an issue in [youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB), attaching your idea.log

Comment: cool, I'll try that tonight, I'm at work, and my issue is happening at home.